# R remainder Function, Extract Specific Value

Tags: r, function, vector, extract, modulo

I'm working to write a function in R that gives out vectors of numeric indices where a vector divided by a number that has no remainder is listed in a resultant vector.

this is what I have so far

```
myfunction <-function(x,d)
{ 
    {y<- x%%d 
    return(y)}
}
```

if you input in:

```
myfunction(x=2:12,d=3)
```

the results comes out as:

```
[1] 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0
```

At the point that I am at, I am trying to extract all values of 0 since those indicate no remainder being present. I don't know how to go about doing that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myfunction <- function(x,d) which(x%%d==0)
x <- 2:12
x[myfunction(x,3)]
```

Any particular reason you want to do this via a function? Otherwise you could just do

```
x[x%%3==0]
```

Comment: I'm just trying different things; how would you go about defining a default value for "d" in the function if none is given?

Comment: @TomRobert In the function arguments: `myfunction <- function(x,d=3) which(x%%d==0)`

Comment: @BlueMagister  I made a misstep and realized it just now! thank you!